# How to Enable Mouse Wheel to scroll Scrollbar in Checklist using Tix Python

Tags: python, tkinter, tix

How to enable Mouse Wheel for scrolling window.I can scroll the window using scroll bar but I want to scroll the window using Mouse Wheel.

Please tell me how to do ?

Is it there any method available in `Tix` ?

```
import Tix

class View(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.makeCheckList()

    def makeCheckList(self):
        self.cl = Tix.CheckList(self.root, browsecmd=self.selectItem)
        self.cl.pack()
        self.cl.hlist.add("CL1", text="checklist1")
        self.cl.setstatus("CL1", "off")

        self.cl.hlist.add("CL1.Item1", text="subitem1")
        self.cl.setstatus("CL1.Item1", "off")
        self.cl.hlist.add("CL1.Item2", text="subitem2")
        self.cl.setstatus("CL1.Item2", "off")
        self.cl.hlist.add("CL1.Item3", text="subitem3")
        self.cl.setstatus("CL1.Item3", "off")
        self.cl.hlist.add("CL1.Item4", text="subitem4")
        self.cl.setstatus("CL1.Item4", "off")
        self.cl.hlist.add("CL1.Item5", text="subitem5")
        self.cl.setstatus("CL1.Item5", "off")
        self.cl.hlist.add("CL1.Item6", text="subitem6")
        self.cl.setstatus("CL1.Item6", "off")
        self.cl.hlist.add("CL1.Item7", text="subitem7")
        self.cl.setstatus("CL1.Item7", "off")
        self.cl.hlist.add("CL1.Item8", text="subitem8")
        self.cl.setstatus("CL1.Item8", "off")

        self.cl.hlist.add("CL2", text="item2")
        self.cl.setstatus("CL2", "on")

        self.cl.hlist.add("CL2.Item1", text="subitem1")
        self.cl.setstatus("CL2.Item1", "on")
        self.cl.hlist.add("CL2.Item2", text="subitem2")
        self.cl.setstatus("CL2.Item2", "on")
        self.cl.hlist.add("CL2.Item3", text="subitem3")
        self.cl.setstatus("CL2.Item3", "on")
        self.cl.hlist.add("CL2.Item4", text="subitem4")
        self.cl.setstatus("CL2.Item4", "on")



        self.cl.autosetmode()

    def selectItem(self, item):
        print item, self.cl.getstatus(item)

def main():
    root = Tix.Tk()
    view = View(root)
    root.update()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output of This code:

[image]

Comment: Does the function in [this lookalike](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22996833/2564301) question help?

Comment: No i have not used canvas and I am asking for Tix @usr2564301

Comment: But it does show how to bind mouse events to another object, doesn't it? So you can presumably bind to the scroll function.

Comment: but that question have not got correct answer and i am New in tkinter so i don't have more idea about that @usr2564301